# PATH system variable capitalization in Java

Tags: java, windows, variables, system-variable

So i went through all kinds of similar questions but couldn‘t find one specifically answering THIS:
From what i know, the `JAVA_HOME` system variable is case-sensitive and should always be capitalized.

But what about the (optional) `PATH` variable? Should it be capitalized? Always? Does it matter?

Because my System e.g. already has a `Path` variable, but not capitalized, instead written like here. Should you then use the already existing one or create a capitalized version in addition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the `Path` environment variable (in Windows), or `PATH` in Unix has any effect on the JVM, other than being used by the underlying operating system if you use the Java libraries to run other processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to 
[Environment Variables in Windows/macOS/Linux
PATH, CLASSPATH, JAVA_HOME](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html)
, environment variables are case-sensitive on Linux and MacOS (and UNIX) but case-insensitive on Windows.

And here's a Microsoft source for that information: [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0):

> "**Remarks**:
>
> *Environment variable names are case-sensitive on Linux and macOS but are not case-sensitive on Windows.*"

Note that this applies to *all* environment variables, not just `PATH`, `CLASSPATH` `JAVA_PATH`.

However, on both Linux, MacOS and Windows, it is conventional to use all uppercase when writing environment variable names in scripts, etc.

Comment: So i should NEED to put it in caps to work on windows? Are there other sources, like oracle themselves, explicitely mentioning this somewhere i don‘t know, just wondering   ?

Comment: No, you don't **need** to.

Comment: It is not Oracle who specify the behavior of environment variables.

Comment: Ok, thank you both (stephen c , tgdavies), i will add it to the existing `Path` then, have a nice one